# Run headful chrome with selenium in a docker container

Tags: java, docker, selenium, google-chrome

I'm trying to run headful (not headless) chrome in a docker container with chrome driver and selenium. I'm using Java

What is the proper way to go about this?

I followed this guide (https://medium.com/dot-debug/running-chrome-in-a-docker-container-a55e7f4da4a8) and was able to create a docker container that I can connect to locally, but I'm having trouble translating it over to selenium

What I want to do is to create a docker container wherein my Java code can start up chromedriver in headful mode without crashing. Selenium doesn't give me a way to use 'xvfb-run' before starting chrome, so I need to be able to start xvfb another way and have chrome able to figure out how to use xvfb.

Is there a certain command to run that would start xvfb in the background, after which chrome should be able to figure out how to use it?

I don't need to see the UI, I just need it to be able to run in headful mode. I'm using it for unit tests where the website behaves differently in headful vs headless mode