# Running tests in a visible Chrome window (headful Chrome?) with Jest and Puppeteer inside Docker inside WSL

Tags: docker, google-chrome, puppeteer

I've got a pretty elaborate end-to-end test suite driven by Jest and Puppeteer.

Puppeteer can be started Chrome in headless or headful mode:

```
puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
```

I've dockerized the app and the test suite. It's running perfectly in headless mode, but I've lost the ability to run it in headful mode: my headful Chrome is on the Windows host, and my Puppeteer is in Docker in WSL, where a headless Chrome is installed.

**How do I use host OS Chrome in headful mode when running Puppeteer tests in Docker?**

In a different project, I've had a test suite start a dev server, offer an URL. I could open that URL in the host OS Chrome, and tests would run there. But Puppeteer seems more elaborate than that.

PS Homework

- [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70341418/901944) links to [this article](https://medium.com/dot-debug/running-chrome-in-a-docker-container-a55e7f4da4a8) that suggests starting a window manager inside the Docker container and connecting to it remotely in a VNC fashion. I don't like that, I want to use the actual Chrome app in my host OS (or any browser, for that matter).
- [Another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51667599/901944), answer suggests the same approach, and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49426599/901944) are VNC instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is really simple.

## Remote debugging

1. Add the `"--remote-debugging-port=9222"` to `{args: []}` that you pass into `puppeteer.launch()`.
2. Launch.
3. Open `chrome://inspect` in Chrome on your host OS and wait for an entry to appear.
4. Use the `Inspect` button/link.

You'll see a normal Chrome window with devtools and a page, except the page will be rendered in VNC style (remote desktop style): the viewport will be sized according to Puppeteer settings and scaled to fit your screen.

Comment: This solution is available [since 2011](https://blog.chromium.org/2011/05/remote-debugging-with-chrome-developer.html). I can't believe that some developers are still using VNC to access Chrome windows in Docker. 